# mysql backup issue

Tags: mysql

I've performed

```
mysqldump -uroot --add-drop-table --default-character-set=latin1 dbname >/backup/new.sql
```

DB 7GB
issue it take tooo much and the output is still 0 size , and mysqladmin processlist show

```
| 8219 | root | localhost | dbname | Query   | 1413 |       | LOCK TABLES `wp_10000_comments` READ /*!32311 LOCAL */,`wp_10000_links` READ /*!32311 LOCAL
```

Any clue whats goin on ? logs show nothing

Comment: I think this should be on serverfault instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mysqlroot
mysql>kill 8219;

You should dump  backup on slave becouse  your primary database can't handle it.
If you use innodb try XtraBackup http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/